# How can I filter by city in the Places API using nearby place?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I program this but in my location, I just want to show schools only under San Juan and Manila.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
    sb.append("&radius=3000");
    sb.append("&types=(locality)manila+sanjuan|university");
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyDrFvBwI32y74-TdxcmFyQyAZvV1t5vAKU");
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to implement a post filter on the results of the search. This should be fine if your search radius roughly covers only these two regions.

To post filter, use the address_components returned from PlaceDetails requests (https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details) to filter using the "locality" address component.

Comment: Sir I dont get it can you give example?? Sorry Im new to Google places api. @plexer

Comment: You will need to write a for loop, that loops over each result you get back from the API. For each result, check the address_components.locality property and ignore that place if it is not in San Juan or Manila.